# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int. [SQLSTATE 22018] (Error 245)

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have sql job that is failing and it produce the above error. the job runs Stored Procedure so I tried to run the procedure so I can pin point the issue.. the SP surprisingly is not failing but at the same time not doing the job ( the SP should insert the data to another table which is not doing). I've looked through the SP thoroughly and I am thinking the below line might be the issue ??

I tried to add cast as varchar at the end and it didn't work. the below line should calculate the client age and insert it into 'Age' column data type numeric(18,6)..

columns type:

```
d.DateofBirth  Date
c.dob DateTime
c.datedeath varchar(50)
c.DateofAttendance DateTime
```

Can any one help, please???

```
CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, ISNULL(d.DateofBirth, c.dob),ISNULL(CAST(CASE WHEN 
c.datedeath = '00000000' THEN NULL ELSE c.DateDeath END AS DATE),                                                                                                                                                                            
ISNULL(c.DateofAttendance,GETDATE()))) / 365.25 AS INT) AS age
```

Comment: This line is not the issue. At no point is any conversion between `VARCHAR` and `INT` involved, except possibly if `00000000` was converted, but that conversion would always succeed. Look further. Common culprits of this error is inadvertently comparing a `VARCHAR` column with an `INT` value instead of a string, which implicitly converts the column values to `INT`, rather than the `INT` to a `VARCHAR`.

Comment: thank you.. how can I debug the SP to find the line with the issue if the SP is succeeding ?? any idea?

Comment: @JeroenMostert - That depends on the datatypes of the columns.  If `d.DateofBirth` is an `INT` and `c.dob` is a `VARCHAR()` then `ISNULL(d.DateofBirth, c.dob)` could be a problem....  After all, `c.datedeath` is certainly a string, so anything is possible...

Comment: Please confirm the data types of all of the columns referenced by this expression.

Comment: @MatBailie: you're technically correct, and I considered it, but that would mean either column is a `DATETIME` stored as an `INT` and relying on implicit conversion to work. That's possible, but supremely unlikely, and I wouldn't focus time on it as opposed to looking at other places first.

Comment: Basically Sql Server will try to implicitly convert any string type to int whenever you compare (or try to concatenate) them.

Comment: @Ayman: take the stored procedure definition, convert the parameters to variables, execute it manually. If the line number doesn't give you enough clues, divide and conquer by selectively eliminating statements until you've found the offending one. Unfortunately T-SQL's help in debugging these things is nonexistent.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it's a cleaner approach and depending on your data types could have a different behaviour.

```
DATEDIFF(
  YEAR,
  ISNULL(d.DateofBirth, c.dob),
  COALESCE(
    CAST(NULLIF(c.datedeath, '00000000') AS DATE),
    c.DateofAttendance,
    GETDATE()
  )
)
```

If that doesn't help, confirm the exact data types of the columns you are referencing in this expression.

If that doesn't help, divide an conquer your SP.  As @JeroenMostert said; execute each part fo the SP in sequence until you have rigorously identified which part of it is actually generating the error.

For example, in the expression above, if it's generating an error you could try Just the `COALESCE()` part, and see if that works or not...

```
  COALESCE(
    CAST(NULLIF(c.datedeath, '00000000') AS DATE),
    c.DateofAttendance,
    GETDATE()
  )
```

Finally, for the love of all things good, consider amending your data structure so that dates are actually held as DATE and not VARCHAR or INT.

Comment: I followed your example and it didn't work then i tried the second part for testing and i got this error:     Implicit conversion from data type datetime to numeric is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: You're trying to do too much.  The error message appears to be that you're trying to INSERT the result in to the destination.  I'm suggesting you just run the SELECT statement, separately from the rest of the Stored Procedure.  If you keep trying to run the whole SP to debug this, you'll be here forever.